# org.json.JSONArray to payload in Mulesoft

Tags: java, json, transform, dataweave, org.json

I'm using a java class to transform a datastructure in my mule application. At the end of my flow I would like to access the result and return it as `application/json`.
When debugging I get these values for payload:
[image: Mule Debug]
The Transform component recognizes a payload of type `org.json.JSONArray`. Under it a var `myArrayList`, which I didn't assign that holds all values.
The getNodes() method in java looks like this:

```
public JSONArray getNodes() {
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    for(Node node : nodes) {
        arr.put(node.getJSON());
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Where the return value is correct.
I tried setting the MIME type of the Invoke component to `application/json` or `text/plain`, both of which resulted in an error.
I tried returning the payload as `output application/json---payload` which resulted in an array of empty objects the size of my return value.
When looking at the watch I get the list by accessing `payload.myArrayList`, but can't seem to get the value in a transform component.
The flow looks like this.
[image: Flow]
How I return json from `JSONArray` in mulesoft?

Edit: Solution:

```
public Node[] getNodes() {
    assignParentIds();
    assignNextIds();
    assignChildIds();
        
    Node[] nodeArr = new Node[nodes.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        nodeArr[i] = nodes.get(i);
    }
    return nodeArr;
}
```

[image: Node Metadata]

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    hierarchieSet: payload map ( item , index ) -> {
        zshop: item.zshop,
        nodeid: item.nodeid,
        nodename: item.nodename,
        tlevel: item.tlevel,
        parentid: item.parentid,
        childid: item.childid,
        nextid: item.nextid
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a custom Java component instead of using Transform Message (DataWeave) to read the input and make all the transformation? If you provide the input and expected output it could be easier to do all in a single DataWeave script.

Comment: Couple of questions here @Peter -A)Do you use the Java method only to perform transformation?         B)After the Get Nodes Invoke  component, do you intend to perform some more transformation in the Transform Message?      C) After the Get Nodes Invoke  component have you tried reading the payload in the Transform message as:- 
%dw 2.0 
output application/json 
--- 
read(payload,"application/json")

Comment: @aled It's a nested structure that is not trivial to flatten in the intended way. I already posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908969/recursivly-traverse-and-flatten-json-object-in-dataweave

Comment: @TheOtherGuy Yes, only do a transformation. There may be some minor transformation later. I tried `%dw 2.0 output application/json --- read(payload,"application/json")`, but there was an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect DataWeave understand `org.json.JSONArray` as an iterable because it implements `Iterable<Object>`, however it doesn't understand particularly JSON nodes. For DataWeave `application/json` is a string or stream that contains a 'textual' representation of JSON. A third party library that represents JSON using Java objects as its implementation is just not going to be understood as JSON and it is not the correct usage of the `application/json` MIME type.

You should serialize the resulting JSON array back to a text document to be used as the input of the Transform processor.

Alternatively you could convert the JSON structures to plain Java objects (POJOs) an use as `application/java`. That should be more efficient because avoids converting to JSON and parsing it again.